# An algebraic inequality in three real variables

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Is it true that
$$(v-u)^2+(w-u)^2+(w-v)^2 \\ 
+\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+u^2}{1+v^2}}
+\sqrt{\frac{1+v^2}{1+u^2}}\right) (w-u)(w-v) \\ 
-\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+u^2}{1+w^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{1+w^2}{1+u^2}}\right) (w-v)(v-u) \\ 
-\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+w^2}{1+v^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{1+v^2}{1+w^2}}\right) (v-u) (w-u)>0$$
for any real $u,v,w$ such that $u<0<v<w$?

Certain numerical evidence suggests it is true.

This inequality arose in the [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/435844/36721).

Comment: people on AOPS could probably solve this very quickly

Comment: @mathworker21 : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Substituting $u=\tan U, v=\tan V, w=\tan W$ gives a surd-free inequality in $\sin U,\cos U,\sin V,\cos V,\sin W,\cos W$ but I don't see what to do with it.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @mathworker21 : No such luck in this case so far. I posted the question there (https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2971952_an_algebraic_inequality_in_three_real_variables) 9 hours ago, and no responses yet.

Comment: (continuing) After discarding a positive denominator, it becomes a linear combination of cosines of linear combinations of $U,V,W$, with terms like $-\frac14\cos(2V-2W)$. Quite a lot of terms, alas, and I still don't know what to do with it.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay : Thank you for your further comment.

Comment: @mathworker21 : Still no responses there on AoPS. I will let you know if/when I get any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the inequality in terms of $a,b,c>1$ via $u=(\frac{1}{a}-a)/2$, $v=(b-\frac{1}{b})/2$, and $w=(c-\frac{1}{c})/2$. Note that $\sqrt{1+u^2}=\frac{1+a^2}{2a}$ and so on. Then the conjectured inequality is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
 ((c - b)(a + c)(a + b))^2(a^2b^2c^2-a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2+ab+ac-bc+1)>0.
\end{equation}
Note that the second factor equals
\begin{equation}
a^2bc(bc-1) + abc(b+c-1) + ab + ac +1,
\end{equation}
which is positive since $b,c>1$.

Comment: A nice way to rationalize the square roots! I should remember this substitution.